# BitLocker: Encrypt all hard drives

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, encryption, bitlocker

Since TrueCrypt is gone now, I'm planning in using **BitLocker** to encrypt my drives. I want to encrypt **all** hard drives.

In my computer, I have an **SSD and an HDD**. At best, I want to turn on the computer, enter the complicated and long password only once and have both drives unlocked. When I re-install Windows, I usualy only format the SSD and not the HDD. This is where I want to avoid surprises, such as the HDD not being readable anymore for any reason.

**Specifically therefore I'm asking:**

What is the optimal way for setting up a completely encrypted computer with 2 hard drives?

(This seems to be a common problem, but I did not found a specific solution to it online)

**A summary of the hardware & software configuration:**

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- SSD where basically only Windows is installed. - Ability to format and re-install Windows required!
- HDD on which data is stored

Comment: TrueCrypt isn't gone.  If you trusted it before, there is no reason to stop trusting it, there just simply won't be any updates going forwad to support GPT partitions

Comment: I still trust it, but using obsolete software is not essentially a good idea as at some point, whenever that will is, it WILL not be usable anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [BitLocker Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831507.aspx#BKMK_WhatIsBitLocker)

> **How BitLocker works with fixed and removable data drives**
>
> BitLocker can also be used to protect fixed and removable data drives.
>   When used with data drives, BitLocker encrypts the entire contents of
>   the drive and can be configured by using Group Policy to require that
>   BitLocker be enabled on a drive before the computer can write data to
>   the drive. BitLocker can be configured with the following unlock
>   methods for data drives:
>
> - Automatic unlock. **Fixed data drives can be set to automatically unlock on a computer where the operating system drive is encrypted.**
>     Removable data drives can be set to automatically unlock on a computer
>     running Windows 8 after the password or smart card is initially used
>     to unlock the drive. However, removable data drives must always have
>     either a password or smart card unlock method in addition to the
>     automatic unlock method.

Comment: Which means encrypting them separately and the (D:) automatically unlocks after the (C:) is unlocked. Thank you for this!